# Phalcon framework - add related models

Tags: php, orm, phalcon

I have an object, `Request`, with a has-many relationship to `RequestItem` (aliased to `items`).  So `Request->items` is a Simple Resultset.

I see in the docs there is a way to update related records with `update()`, and delete related records with `delete()`.  Is there any way to add related records in a similar fashion?  I tried just $this->items[] = $Item, but got a "Cursor is an immutable ArrayAccess object" error.

I basically want to simply add a new related record to Request, and have Request->items reflect the addition.  I was unable to find anything in the docs, which surprised me actually.

**This question is over a year old at this point. New answers are not necessary or helpful**

Answer (score 1):

When you have a one to many relationship and you want add new items you have to set the array with the objects that do you want to add. example:

```
$Request = new Request();
// ... sets the attributes for Request object
$item1 = new RequestItem();
$item1->attr1 = $value1; 
// ... add the attributes you want
$item2 = new RequestItem();
$item2->attr1 = $value2;
// ... and so on
$items = array($item1, $item2 /*, ... all that you need */);
$Request->items = $items;
if ($Request->save()) {
    echo 'Good';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must initialize belongsTo(Request) in the RequestItem model.
when you add it, you create

```
$newItem = new RequestItem();
$newItem->setRequest($request);
$newItem->create();
```

then you will be able to get all items using $request->getItems();

Answer (score 0):

please show me your db table structure with full realation's.

and you most use method in this page:
http://docs.phalconphp.com/pt/latest/reference/models.html#defining-relationships

Answer (score 0):

```
class Request extends \Phalcon\MVC\Model
{
  public function initialize()
  {
    $this->hasMany('id', 'RequestItem', 'request_id');
  }
}
```

$this->hasMany('**foreign key of main model**', '**related model name**', '**foreign key for related**');

```
class RequestItem extends \Phalcon\MVC\Model
{
  public function initialize()
  {
    $this->belongsTo('request_id', 'Request', 'id');
  }
}
```

$this->hasMany('**foreign key for related**', '**main model name**', '**foreign key of main model**');

As long as it's all set properly you can perform creation of related records like this:

```
class RequestsController extends \Phalcon\MVC\Controller
{
  public function createItemsAction($RequestId)
  {
    $Request = Request::findFirst($RequestId);
    $RequestItem = new RequestItem();
    $RequestItem->Request = $Request;
    $RequestItem->otherproperties = .....
  }
}
```

Hope that is close to what you needed

Answer (score -1):

Use following code to add that is save:

```
$user = new Users();
$success = $user->save($this->request->getPost(), array('name', 'email'));
```